# When should I use O_CLOEXEC when I open file in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, exec

My process forks several times, and each time the child will exec - means I want it to run some other program.

In the main process I open a file descriptor with the `open()` syscall.

Would it be correct to give it a flag `O_CLOEXEC` so the new program that I run with `exec()` wouldn't have the fd resource?

Comment: see also: [man 2 open](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, unless you need the program you exec to have access to that file descriptor. You can also close the file descriptor manually in the child process before calling exec, but that's more error prone.

Comment: An old (but error-prone) practice was to `for (int=3; i<256; i++) close(i);` just before the `execve`, leaving only stdin, stdout, stderr ....