# When should you use system(3) to run an external process?

Tags: python, c, os.system

C supplies the standard function [`system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) to run a subprocess using the **shell**, and many languages provide similar functions, like [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html#index-system_0028_0029-function), [Perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#system-LIST) (with a single argument), and [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php).  Sometimes those functions are [criticized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21661905/8586227) as being unsuitable for general use, either on [security grounds](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87152177) or because the shell is not portable or [is not the one used interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33992436/8586227).

Some other languages seem to agree: they provide only a means of running a process without the shell, like [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) (which tokenizes any single string argument itself) and [Tcl](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)).  Python provides both a [direct wrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) and a [sophisticated replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) that can avoid using the shell and explicitly **recommends** the latter (as [does the user community](https://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/8586227)).

Certainly the shell is unnecessary complexity for many applications; running an external process at all can bring in issues of [deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49728472/8586227), [orphan processes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/284325/8586227), ambiguous exit statuses, and [file descriptor sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15447657/8586227) and is unnecessary in cases like running `mkdir` or `echo $VAR`.  However, assuming that `system` exists for a reason, **when** is it the right tool to use?

Answer (score 4):

Even assuming a use case for which it's appropriate to run an external process and in particular to run one via the shell (without being able to filter output as with `popen`), for C and Python (that uses the **actual** C `system(3)`) there are additional caveats.  POSIX [specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) additional behavior for `system`: it **ignores** `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` and blocks `SIGCHLD` during its execution.  The rationale is that the user (who can send `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` from the terminal) is [interacting with the subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56053355/8586227), not the parent, during its execution, and that `system` must handle the `SIGCHLD` for its child process without the application's interference.

This directly implies the answer to the question: it is appropriate to use `system` only when

1. The **user** has directly asked for a particular shell command to be executed (*e.g.*, with `!` in `less`), and
2. The application need not react to any **other** child process exiting during this time (*e.g*, it should not be multithreaded).

If #1 is not satisfied, the user is likely to send a terminal signal expecting it to kill the whole process and have it kill only the (unexpected if not invisible) child.  The Linux man pages caution particularly about [using it in a loop](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) that the user cannot then interrupt.  It is possible to notice that a child has exited with a signal and reraise it, but this is unreliable because some programs (*e.g.*, Python) `exit` upon receiving certain signals rather than **reraising** it to indicate why they exited—and because the shell (mandated by `system`!) **conflates** exit statuses with signal-kill statuses.

In Python the error-handling problems are compounded by the fact that `os.system` follows the C exit-status (read: error code) convention instead of reporting failure as an **exception**, inviting the user to ignore the exit status of the child.

Comment: And of course in Python there is never an excuse to use `os.system` as all use cases could be covered with `subprocess.run`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple (in theory), because it's the same answer that applies to many other programming questions: it's appropriate to use `system()` when it makes the programmer's life easier, and makes the user's life no harder.

Spotting when this is true, however, requires considerable judgement, and probably we won't always get it right. But, again, that's true of many judgement calls in programming.

Since most shells are written in C, there's no reason *in principle* why anything done using `system()` can't be done without it. However, sometimes it requires a whole heap of coding to do what can be done in one line by invoking a shell. The same applies to `popen()` which, I guess, raises exactly the same kinds of questions.

Using `system()` raises portability, thread safety, and signal-management concerns.

My experience, unfortunately, is that the situations where `system()` gives the most benefit (to the programmer) are precisely the ones where it will be least portable.

Sometimes concerns like this will suggest a different approach, and sometimes they won't matter -- it depends on the application.